# C# NAudio library, can't list codecs in combo box

Tags: c#, combobox, naudio, codec

I'm trying to list all the codecs possible for audio compression in a combo box. NAudio have source code and a demo application which im trying to emulate in my form application. If anyone can help me, their source code is [here.](https://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NAudioDemo/NetworkChatDemo/NetworkChatPanel.cs)

So they have about 7 other .cs files in their project which resembles the codecs they use so I copied them all into my project. I then copied all the (from what I see) relevant code for listing them in a combo box. No errors so far or anything so I run it and it stops as the value of each codec seems to be null (posted below the code).

Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NAudio.Wave;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using NAudioDemo.NetworkChatDemo;

namespace NAudio_VoIP_UDP
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [ImportMany(typeof(INetworkChatCodec))]
    public IEnumerable<INetworkChatCodec> Codecs { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PopulateCodecsCombo(Codecs);
    }

    private void PopulateCodecsCombo(IEnumerable<INetworkChatCodec> codecs)
    {
        var sorted = from codec in codecs
                     where codec.IsAvailable
                     orderby codec.BitsPerSecond ascending
                     select codec;

        foreach (var codec in sorted)
        {
            string bitRate = codec.BitsPerSecond == -1 ? "VBR" : String.Format("{0:0.#}kbps", codec.BitsPerSecond / 1000.0);
            string text = String.Format("{0} ({1})", codec.Name, bitRate);
            comboBoxCodecs.Items.Add(new CodecComboItem { Text = text, Codec = codec });
        }
        comboBoxCodecs.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    class CodecComboItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public INetworkChatCodec Codec { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Text;
        }
    }
}
}
```

but then when i run the code, it stops here:

```
            var sorted = from codec in codecs
                     where codec.IsAvailable
                     orderby codec.BitsPerSecond ascending
                     select codec;
```

as the value cannot be null.

Below is an image of my solution explorer where you can see all the codecs I added and what should be shown in the combo box:

[image: solution explorer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you copied is using the Microsoft Extensibility Framework, which is why you have `[ImportMany(typeof(INetworkChatCodec))]` at the top. If you also copied those codec files from NAudio, they all include something like `[Export(typeof(INetworkChatCodec))]` in them.

MEF will then scan your program for all instances of `INetworkChatCodec`, create an instance of them, and store the list in `Codecs`. But you need to initialize it.

The code to initialize it is found in the startup code for that demo, but it's pretty standard MEF stuff:

```
var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
var exportFactoryProvider = new ExportFactoryProvider();
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog, exportFactoryProvider);
exportFactoryProvider.SourceProvider = container;
```

Note, though, that this demo was written for .NET 3.5; it includes local references to some MEF bits (they are in the `Lib\MEF` folder), which you'll need in order to use `ExportFactoryProvider`.

IIRC, in .NET 4.5, the `System.ComponentModel.Composition` library is built in, but you would use [`ExportFactory<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382807(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `ExportFactoryProvider` to do an `ImportMany`